# nginx reverse proxy,how can i get the user request domain?

Tags: php, nginx

my nginx.conf code is

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  A.domain.com;
    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass B.domain.com;
    }
}
```

when user request A.domain.com,how can I get the request domain?  when I use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`,what I get is B.domain.com,not A.domain.com.

Answer (score 1):

$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] gives B.domain.com because you have used proxy_pass. 
If you need A.domain.com set a new header `Via` and it's value equal to $host.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name  A.domain.com;
    location / {
        set  $via  "1.0 A.domain.com";
        if ($http_via) {
            set $via  "$http_via, 1.0 A.domain.com";
        }
        proxy_set_header  Via  $via;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass B.domain.com;
    }
}
```

Now you can check for this `Via` header in your script for differentiating.